# Funcionality of macmini applications

Tags: mac-mini, server.app

I just recently bought a mac-mini server and love it. It currently is being used in a small work environment for communication purposes and storage/backup use. However I have noticed that there is a wiki page application residing on the server and available for use. Are there any user guides out there for this application, Im not very familiar with it and want to learn how to use it more in depth.

Also, can this application serve more purpose than just displaying information in a wikipedia format? I'm basically looking for more functionality such as template creation and modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see Apple documentation here: http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/wiki-server.html

and here: http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/resources/documentation.html

That should get you started.

Enjoy!